# Limit character length of mapped value in React

Tags: reactjs, array.prototype.map

I have a functional react component with text that is displayed from a mapped array. How can I limit the character count of `{item.description}` to 250 characters?

```
 import React from "react";

 const Component = props => {
  const classes = props.classes;
  return (
    <div className={classes.container}>
      <ul className={classes.items}>
        {props.children.map((item, i) => (
          <li key={i} className={classes.item}>
            <p className={classes.category}>
              {item.genre} {item.date}
            </p>
            <p className={classes.header}>{item.header}</p>
            <p className={classes.details}>{item.description}</p>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Short and simple:**

```
<p className={classes.details}>{item.description.substring(0, 250)}</p>
```

It will return a substring containing the first 250 characters of `item.description` (or the whole string if it's shorter than 250 chars).

---

**Slightly longer:**

If you want to conditionally add `...` at the end of the truncated string, you can do:

```
<p className={classes.details}>
  {item.description.length > 250 ?
    `${item.description.substring(0, 250)}...` : item.description
  }
</p>
```